# CSS Grid 1 top 3 bottom

Tags: css, css-grid, gallery, photo

im trying to make a photo grid which shows 1 image on top and 3 separate images on the bottom.

[image]

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can read more about CSS GRID on this tutorial.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

[You can use a grid generator like this to make it easily.](https://grid.layoutit.com/)

Note that I putted a red solid 5px border to each `div`, so it is more visible.

You can put your `img src="Your url"`, to show your image

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "main-photo main-photo main-photo"
    "main-photo main-photo main-photo"
    "photo1 photo2 photo3";
}

div{
border:5px solid red;
}

.main-photo { grid-area: main-photo; }
.photo1 { grid-area: photo1; }
.photo2 { grid-area: photo2; }
.photo3 { grid-area: photo3; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="main-photo"><img src=""></img></div>
  <div class="photo1"><img src=""></img></div>
  <div class="photo2"><img src=""></img></div>
  <div class="photo3"><img src=""></img></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using layitoutgrid, but i was using it wrong i think.